# passing query on the same page AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm still fresh in using AJAX and i'm having hard time with it.can you please help me with this? i actually have a dropdown and when i select an item in that dropdown a table of queries should print to the tbody.here's my code:

**the PHP code:**

```
<select id="proj_id" name="proj_id" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">

    <option value="none">---select project---</option>
    <?php
    //Projects
    $r = @mysql_query("SELECT `proj_id`, `proj_name` FROM `projects`");

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $proj_id = $rows['proj_id'];
        $proj_name = $rows['proj_name'];
        echo '<option value='.$proj_id.'>'.$proj_name.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>

<table>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Material Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="project_estmat">
<?php
    //Display Requests
    $r = @mysql_query("SELECT `proj_name`, `mat_name`, `req_qty`, `stat_desc` FROM `requests` JOIN `projects` USING(`proj_id`) JOIN `materials` USING(`mat_id`) JOIN `status` ON(requests.stat_id = status.stat_id)");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['proj_name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['mat_name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['req_qty'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['stat_desc'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**jS CODE:**

```
function myFunction(value){

if(value!="none")
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'content/admin/requests.php',
        data: { proj_id: value},
        success: function(data) {
    $('#project_estmat').html(data);

    }
});
}
else
{
    $('#project_estmat').html("select an item");
}

}
```

and I have this PHP code that should be in the #project_estmat which is a table. And I think this is where the problem lies. Because everytime I select an item, nothing is printing in the table. It shows empty data.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['proj_id'])) {

    $r = @mysql_query("SELECT `proj_name`, `mat_name`, `req_qty`, `stat_desc` FROM `requests` JOIN `projects` USING(`proj_id`) JOIN `materials` USING(`mat_id`) JOIN `status` ON(requests.stat_id = status.stat_id)");
    if($r){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['proj_name'].'</td>'; 
            echo '<td>'.$row['mat_name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['req_qty'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['stat_desc'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have wrapped $.ajax function with, `${`
it should be like the following, and try using [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/), and remove the inline function calling when you do this,

```
$('#proj_id').change(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
    if(value!="none"){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'content/admin/requests.php',
            data: { proj_id: value},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#project_estmat').html(data);
                alert(data);//check whats coming from the server side 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

tested out with a simplified php code to the server end such as the following,

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['proj_id'])) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>A</td>'; 
            echo '<td>B</td>';
            echo '<td>C</td>';
            echo '<td>D</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

}
?>
```

Comment: whats coming from the server side into the ajax success function? you can check this via the way i have shown with an alert()

Comment: you're missing a `{` after the if syntax

Comment: nothing.when i select an item from the dropbox it returns empty data.

Comment: @chris you need to check whats being outputted by php file in the server side, its difficult for us to check because its dynamic data you are referring to

Comment: but then if i change the last code with a simple table.it returns the table.but when query is involved.its returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

everything looks fine except you have a '$' extra in your if condition

```
if(value!="none")
${  //here
```

removing the '$' sign should work...

Comment: `alert(value)` in your function `myFunction` and check if you are getting the right value or not..

Comment: so there is the problem... check your `onchange` function since it is not returning any values...

Comment: but then if i change the last code with a simple table.it returns the table.i think it's not in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the function mysql_query since its deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You better use the PHP PDO class (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Dont suppress your error using '@' error_compression operator. Remove the @ symbol from mysql_query and try debugging your code.

Comment: there's no difference.it's still the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try building a string and sending it back.

```
$str = '';
if($r){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        $str .= '<tr>';
        $str .= '<td>'.$row['proj_name'].'</td>'; 
        $str .= '<td>'.$row['mat_name'].'</td>';
        $str .= '<td>'.$row['req_qty'].'</td>';
        $str .= '<td>'.$row['stat_desc'].'</td>';
        $str .= '</tr>';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Then when the loop is done we can send the string back. While the `dataType` property `.ajax()` uses `intelligent parsing` to decide what type of data is being sent back and how to construct the returned object, you should just declare it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'content/admin/requests.php',
    data: { proj_id: value},
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#project_estmat').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: it still returns an empty table.